# Solving a system of four polynomial equations for an expression

Tags: equation-solving

An [AIME competition question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkFgyjjRyKw) is:

Given $a,b,x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and

$$a x + b y = 3,  \quad a x^3 + b y^3 = 16$$

$$a x^2 + b y^2 = 7,  \quad a x^4 + b y^4 =42$$

find

$$a x^5 + b y^5$$

The direct approach doesn't seem to work:

```
Solve[a x + b y == 3 \[And] a x^3 + b y^3 == 16 \[And] 
  a x^2 + b y^2 == 7 \[And] a x^4 + b y^4 == 42 \[And] 
  a x^5 + b y^5 == k, 
 {k}, Reals]
```

(Incidentally, the answer is $20$.)

What tricks or constraints or substitutions would allow *Mathematica* to solve this problem?

Comment: One quick way: `In[227]:= 
GroebnerBasis[{a*x + b*y - 3, a*x^3 + b*y^3 - 16, a*x^2 + b*y^2 - 7, 
   a*x^4 + b*y^4 - 42, a*x^5 + b*y^5 - val}, val, {a, b, x, y}][[1]]

Out[227]= -20 + val`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing all your variables works:

```
k /. Solve[
a x + b y == 3 \[And] a x^3 + b y^3 == 16 \[And] 
 a x^2 + b y^2 == 7 \[And] a x^4 + b y^4 == 42 \[And] 
 a x^5 + b y^5 == k, {a, b, x, y, k}, Reals][[1]] // Simplify
```

Also, **not** listing any variables causes it to treat all free symbols as variables:

```
k /. Solve[a x + b y == 3 \[And] a x^3 + b y^3 == 16 \[And] 
a x^2 + b y^2 == 7 \[And] a x^4 + b y^4 == 42 \[And] 
a x^5 + b y^5 == k, Reals] // Simplify
```

Comment: Oh... thanks!  ($\checkmark$)

Answer (score 3):

I think similar questions were asked and answered a lot.

```
Simplify[a*x^5 + b*y^5,Assumptions -> a*x + b*y == 3 && a*x^3 + b*y^3 == 16 && 
a*x^2 + b*y^2 == 7 &&   a*x^4 + b*y^4 == 42]
```

$20$

Answer (score 3):

- separate the variable and parametric.

```
Solve[a x + b y == 3 ∧ a x^3 + b y^3 == 16 ∧ 
  a x^2 + b y^2 == 7 ∧ a x^4 + b y^4 == 42 ∧ 
  a x^5 + b y^5 == k, {k}, {a, b, x, y}]
```

- use`Reduce`

```
Reduce[a x + b y == 3 ∧ a x^3 + b y^3 == 16 ∧ 
  a x^2 + b y^2 == 7 ∧ a x^4 + b y^4 == 42 ∧ 
  a x^5 + b y^5 == k, {k}]
```

- use `ForAll`

```
ForAll[{a, b, x, y}, 
 a x + b y == 3 ∧ a x^3 + b y^3 == 16 ∧ 
  a x^2 + b y^2 == 7 ∧ a x^4 + b y^4 == 42, a x^5 + b y^5 == k]
Resolve[%] // Simplify
```

**Appendix**

we can calculate all the `r[n]=a x^n + b y^n` if we provide the  initial condition `r[1] == 3, r[2] == 7, r[3] == 16, r[4] == 42`.

By the uniqueness of such `r[n]`,we only need to find a sequence that satisfied such condition. Here we use the second order difference equation.

```
rsol = RSolve[{r[n + 2] == p*r[n + 1] + q*r[n]}, r, n][[1]];
sol = Solve[{r[1] == 3, r[2] == 7, r[3] == 16, r[4] == 42} /. 
     rsol][[1]];
r /. rsol /. sol
% /@ Range[8] // Simplify
```

$$ \frac{2^{-n-1} \left(-14-2 \sqrt{87}\right)^n}{4263+457 \sqrt{87}}+\frac{1}{19} \left(49-\frac{19}{4263+457 \sqrt{87}}\right) 2^{-n-1} \left(2
   \sqrt{87}-14\right)^n$$

> `{3, 7, 16, 42, 20, 1316, -17664, 297304}`

Comment: I like the completeness.  Thanks.  ($+1$)

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction[{3, 7, 16, 42, 20, 1316}] /@ Range[8] // Simplify`

Comment: Or shorter `Reduce[a x + b y == 3 \[And] a x^3 + b y^3 == 16 \[And] 
  a x^2 + b y^2 == 7 \[And] a x^4 + b y^4 == 42 \[And] 
  a x^5 + b y^5 == k]`.